# Bind to generic property

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, generics, binding

I am trying to bind a ListBox to a property in my ViewModel. What I'd like to do is to be able to swap out that property at any time to another list that has the same field. So at the moment I have this:

```
public List<City> Cities
{
    get { return GetCities(); }
}
```

When I bind this using the usual

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"
```

it works fine. I also have another sealed class called Rivers and the same public property (Name) for that.

```
public List<River> Rivers
{
    get { return GetRivers(); }
}
```

They both have a common property "Name" which is  what the Listbox displays. What's the best way of swapping between Rivers, Cities, and other classes? Theoretically I would like a generic List property which could be bound to and set the value of that to Rivers or Cities etc.. but I don't think it's possible to create a generic List property. All classes are sealed and I can't modify them.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What determines which list is being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't change the original classes, you would probably be best creating two [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) classes for River and City that each implement a common interface with the Name property on it.

That way you can just use a single list to represent each of them, and swap between the two at will.

e.g.

```
public interface INamed
{
   string Name { get; }
}

public class RiverAdapter : INamed
{
  private River _river;
  public string Name { get { return _river.Name; } }
}
public class CityAdapter : INamed
{
  private River _city;
  public string Name { get { return _city.Name; } }
}
```

so your list declaration would become:

```
public IEnumerable<INamed> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 I missed the sealed/can't modify aspect of the OP. The Adapter pattern is a good way to go here.

Comment: Thanks. I tried messing with interfaces but couldn't get them working but this adapter model is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `dynamic` list bound to your `ListBox` and populate that based on what you need to display, and you can use `DisplayMemberPath` to show the `Name` or any other common prerty in the `ListBox`

Working Example:

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<dynamic> _listBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();
    public ObservableCollection<dynamic> ListBoxItems
    {
        get { return _listBoxItems; }
        set { _listBoxItems = value; }
    }


    public List<River> Rivers
    {
        get
        { 
            return new List<River>
            { 
               new River { Name = "River1" } ,
               new River { Name = "River2"}
            };  
        }
    }

    public List<City> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<City>
            { 
               new City { Name = "City1" } ,
               new City { Name = "City2"}
            };  
        }
    }

    private void button_City_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItems.Clear();
        Cities.ForEach(i => ListBoxItems.Add(i));
    }

    private void button_River_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItems.Clear();
        Rivers.ForEach(i => ListBoxItems.Add(i));
    }
}

public sealed class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class River
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="199" Width="191" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}" >
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="0,0,0,29" />
        <Button Content="City" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="button_City_Click"/>
        <Button Content="River" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="button_River_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I get "Cannot convert type Generic.List<Rivers> to Generic.List<dynamic>"

Comment: @NewCode: You can't cast to a List: if you could, you would be able to insert a City in your List of Rivers. That would be wrong. Try IEnumerable<dynamic>.

Comment: Using `dynamic` is rather unnecessary. Having the property as a non-generic `IList` or `ICollection`, or as `IEnumerable<object>`, would work just fine, and using `dynamic` may cause poor performance. The `Binding` doesn't care whether it's an `object` or `dynamic`, it's still going to reflect it anyway.